# Is it possible to change default diff tool for apt (or maybe it is for shell)?

Tags: apt, configuration, default-programs, tools, diff

I'm not sure is it `apt` or `shell` setting or is it a setting at all but whenever there is a conflict on a configuration file while doing `apt upgrade` I'm presented with these options:

```
Y or I : install the package maintainer's version
N or O : keep your currently-installed version
  D    : show the differences betweeen the versions
  Z    : start a shell to examine the situation
```

Is it possible to change the `D` option to use something else (e.g., `mcdiff`)?

Going with `Z` option and `sudo mcdiff $DPKG_CONFFILE_OLD $DPKG_CONFFILE_NEW` and then `exit` is a bit annoying.

Comment: Unfortunately `diff` and `sdiff` appear to be hard coded into the `/usr/bin/ucf` script

Comment: @steeldriver, looks like you are right and the answear to my question is simply: no. You may post your comment as an answer. I'll accept it.